# Does $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

The Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to 1 for positive real numbers $x$.

Does this also apply for negative real numbers $x$?

**Edit:**

The choice of the root can be arbitrary.

Comment: How do you define $x^{1/n}$?

Comment: As the nth-root of x.

Comment: There are multiple roots though, whence the question.

Comment: That doesn’t work for even$n$

Comment: It is the more general case of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ which also converges to 1. I think that it was also discussed here on the stackexchange.

Comment: Aren't you disturbed by the fact that $i$ has $n$ $n^\text{th}$ roots?

Comment: Should I be disturbed, @JoséCarlosSantos? Could you elaborate on what you are hinting at? Thank you.

Comment: You wrote that $i^{1/n}$ is **the** $n^\text{th}$ root of $i$, which assumes that there is only one such root. But there are in fact $n$ of them.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Thank you, Jose. I forgot this for a moment... So can 1 be one of those roots? I need this as a lemma for a proof of mine. If this doesn't hold then my proof is "wrong".

Comment: Ah, wait a minute... I think my problem is more that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0 and if this implies that $i^0$ is 1.

Comment: You won't still have a real valued sequence if you allow for negative values of x; and “the choice of the root can be arbitrary” is as sloppy as it sounds. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that this just hold for some choice of roots, as by your comment, then indeed that works.

Let $x$ be a non-zero complex number. There exists a sequence $x_n$ such that 
$x_n^n=x$ for each $n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =1$.

To see this write $x$ in trigonometric form $x =r e^{i \theta}$ with $r$ a positive real and $\theta \in [0,2\pi [$.

Now set $x_n = r^{1/n} e^{i\theta/n}$.

Then clearly $x_n^n =x$ and by the result you recalled $r^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ and  $e^{i\theta/n}$  also tends to $1$ as  $\theta/n$ tends to $0$.